# Creating feature class representation using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, representation

I have written a script which allows me to select multiple feature classes and apply both a representation (based on a template layer) and set a transparency value before adding to the map. Unfortunately only the first layer receives the representation. What am I doing wrong?

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
addlayers = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # featureclasses (multivalue entry)
theFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # workspace - geodatabase
theRep = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) # featureclass with representation
theValue = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) # Transparency value

# Set reference layer and create representations for selection
rep_layer = "{0}\{1}".format(theFolder,theRep)

# Add layers and transparency
theLayers = addlayers.split(";")
for layer in theLayers:
    lay = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer.strip("'"))
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lay)
    for child in desc.representations:
        if child.dataType =="RepresentationClass":
            pass
        else:
            rep_name = "{0}_rep".format(desc.baseName)
            arcpy.AddRepresentation_cartography(lay,rep_name,"RuleID","Override","STORE_CHANGE_AS_OVERRIDE",rep_layer,"Assign")
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,lay)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    lay.transparency = int(theValue)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `desc = arcpy.Describe(lay)` instead of `desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)`? And why `theRep` is never used in the script?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov, well spotted, had to strip this out a bigger script so made a couple of mistakes transcribing,...

Comment: Please include `print` statements to show us a test value for each variable that you are receiving from your tool dialog.